# About tarjan algorithm, why can't we take low[v] instead of disc[v] when considering the backward edge?

Tags: algorithm, tarjans-algorithm

I read an article about Tarjan's algorithm,
[blog](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tarjan-algorithm-find-strongly-connected-components/). In this article, the author asks a question:

> In case two, can we take low[v] instead of disc[v] ?? . Answer is NO. If you can think why answer is NO, you probably understood the Low and Disc concept.

I don't know why. When I am reading the similar article in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm), I found that the code can be like that:

```
     else if (w.onStack) then
    // Successor w is in stack S and hence in the current SCC
    v.lowlink  := min(v.lowlink, w.lowlink)
```

I wanna know why the author say the answer is NO.
Thanks for answering my question.
Have a good day.

Comment: I can't tell for sure (Tarjan used `min(low, disc)` in his original paper), but to me either way is fine. It certainly does matter when you search for bridges and/or articulation points - in such a case using `low` would imply that you can jump in the backward direction multiple times (not using only a single edge) and thus skip articulation points. However, In the case of finding sccs, all you need is to know if you can go to *some* earlier vertex within the same scc, and so, you make `low[v] <> disc[v]`, and that's what matters.

Comment: Using `min(low, disc)` is closer to the actual definition of what `low` function is which in turn is present also in the aforementioned algorithms, thus I guess that's the reason why `disc` is here.